# why we call array a sequential container?

Tags: c++

In c++, One common property of all sequential containers is that the elements can be accessed sequentially.  (wiki)

Why we call an array a sequential container but accessing array elements is not sequentially, e.g. accessing array[0] jumps to accessing array[10]?

Comment: Because it is possible to access array items sequentially like `array[0]` `array[1]` `array[2]`... Even though array supports random access it won't stop being sequential all of it sudden.

Comment: You may be confusing with the more common requirement where "sequential" refers to the layout of the array elements in memory.  Of course, in arrays _sequential access_ is also possible, and so is _random access_.  Since you appear to be quoting information from somewhere else, you should add a link to the source of that information.

Comment: An array or vector has a inherent order. Something an map for example generally lacks.

Comment: Who are those "we"? Please quote your sources. Links are also nice.

Comment: Hi, according to the wiki page, 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_container_(C%2B%2B)

Comment: Hi, according the wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_container_(C%2B%2B),  array and list are sequential container.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bottom line: Accessing elements is random, however the storage is sequential.

With an array (for arguments sake it's 10 elements long) each element is lined up one after each other in memory (i.e. it has sequential storage - much like the house numbers on a street). If I need to visit the fifth house on the street, I simply count five houses from the start of the street, and I'm there (this is random access).

Non-random access would involve a data structure such as a linked list. That arrangement is similar to lending a DVD to a friend. You ask your friend if he has the DVD, turns out he lent it to Dave, so you visit Dave, and he tells you Sue now has it, so you visit Sue, and she sends you to malcom, repeat until found....

If we really wanted to (lets be honest, 99% of the time) we'd end up accessing a sequential container sequentially...

```
 for(auto&& item : items)
```

However we can access them randomly if we wanted to:

```
 items[rand() % items.size()]
```

To do the same thing with a linked list we'd have to start at the first friend, and travel between each one until we found the 5th item in the list.

Comment: Hi, according to wiki page 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_container_(C%2B%2B), list and array are both sequential container. But memory storage of a List is not sequential....

Comment: a list does not offer random access (unlike an array).

Comment: Then what a sequential container means? Does it mean that the container has sequential memory storage or that the container support sequential access?  Thank you.